# Atmel DMA controller programming

Tags: c, linux, driver, dma, spi

I'm working on a Linux kernel module to read counts from a chip on the SPI bus of a AT91SAM9x25EK system on a chip.  I'm finding some unusual behaviour though.  The chip should return sets of numbers that look like this:

170, 172, 172, 172, 170, 173, 173, 173, 170, 174, 174, 174, 170, 175, 175, 175, etc.

Essentially, I should see 170 followed by 3 bytes, which increase with each read.

This works just fine with PIO, but isn't practical.  I have to read 4 bytes every 200us, which ties up the entire CPU.  So, DMA is the way to go.

However, I have 2 issues with DMA.  First comes from atmel_spi.c  The top of the file says:

```
#if defined(CONFIG_SPI_ATMEL_DMA)
/* use PIO for small transfers, avoiding DMA setup/teardown overhead and
 * cache operations; better heuristics consider wordsize and bitrate.
 */
#define DMA_MIN_BYTES   16
```

Obviously the 4 bytes I need are less than the DMA minimum requirement.  This means either I have to read 16 bytes at a time from the chip, or change this #define to 4.  In either case, the result is the same.  Activating the DMA controller cuts the CPU usage to less than half, but mucks up my results.  Now, my chip spits back stuff like this:

170, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 0, 0

My 170 marker is still there, but all the other reads return 0's.  It doesn't seem to matter if I read the correct number of bytes or not, every time I use the DMA controller I get 0's for every value, and I'm completely stumped.

If anyone has an idea of either what has gone wrong, or has an idea of how I can circumvent the whole DMA issue completely, I'd be excited to try it out.  The 200us is a hard requirement, but I may have more breathing room in the rest of the implementation.

This is my init function which sets up the kernel buffers and DMA:

```
static int __init quicklogic_init_spi(void)
{
int error;

quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff = kmalloc(4, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);
if (!quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff) {
    error = -ENOMEM;
    goto quicklogic_init_error;
}
memset(quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff, 0, 4);

quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff = kmalloc(SPI_BUFF_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);
if (!quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff) {
    error = -ENOMEM;
    goto quicklogic_init_error;
}
memset(quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff, 9, SPI_BUFF_SIZE);

/* configure DMA recieve buffer */
quicklogic_ctl.rx_dma = dma_map_single(&quicklogic_dev.spi_device->dev,
    (void*)quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff, SPI_BUFF_SIZE, DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
quicklogic_ctl.tx_dma = dma_map_single(&quicklogic_dev.spi_device->dev,
    (void*)quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff, 4, DMA_TO_DEVICE);
/*Tell the driver we want DMA */ 
quicklogic_ctl.msg.is_dma_mapped = 1;
error = spi_register_driver(&quicklogic_driver);
if (error < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "spi_register_driver() failed %d\n", error);
    goto quicklogic_init_error;
}

error = add_quicklogic_device_to_bus();
if (error < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "add_quicklogic_to_bus() failed\n");
    spi_unregister_driver(&quicklogic_driver);
    goto quicklogic_init_error; 
}

quicklogic_prepare_spi_message();
/*my messages are always the same, so set this up only once*/

return 0;

 quicklogic_init_error:

if (quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff) {
    kfree(quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff);
    quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff = 0;
}

if (quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff) {
    kfree(quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff);
    quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff = 0;
}

return error;
}
```

Also, this is my function which sets up the SPI transfers.  Essentially I queue a big set of transfers into one message.

```
#define SPI_TRANSFERS   150528
#define SPI_MSG_LEN     4
#define SPI_MSG_DELAY   200 /*in microseconds*/
#define SPI_BUFF_SIZE   602112 /*can hold 150528 four byte transfers (30 seconds)*/
#define USER_BUFF_SIZE  602112

const char this_driver_name[] = "quicklogic";


struct quicklogic_control {
struct spi_message msg;
struct spi_transfer transfer[SPI_TRANSFERS];
u8 *tx_buff; 
u8 *rx_buff;
dma_addr_t tx_dma;
dma_addr_t rx_dma;
};

static struct quicklogic_control quicklogic_ctl;


struct quicklogic_dev {
struct semaphore spi_sem;
struct semaphore fop_sem;
dev_t devt;
struct cdev cdev;
struct class *class;
struct spi_device *spi_device;
char *user_buff;
u8 test_data;   
};

static struct quicklogic_dev quicklogic_dev;


static void quicklogic_prepare_spi_message(void)
{
int i;
spi_message_init(&quicklogic_ctl.msg);

for (i=0; i<SPI_TRANSFERS; i++) {
    quicklogic_ctl.transfer[i].tx_buf = quicklogic_ctl.tx_buff;
    quicklogic_ctl.transfer[i].rx_buf = quicklogic_ctl.rx_buff + (i * SPI_MSG_LEN);
    quicklogic_ctl.transfer[i].len = SPI_MSG_LEN;
    quicklogic_ctl.transfer[i].delay_usecs = SPI_MSG_DELAY;

    spi_message_add_tail(&quicklogic_ctl.transfer[i], &quicklogic_ctl.msg);
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should ask this question [here on this SE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/28047/)

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? Have you modified the dts? How?

Comment: I did solve this.  It was a while ago now, but I'm pretty sure the answer was to stick with PIO mode.  Even though the PIO transfers are slower, it's worth avoiding the DMA overhead.  I think my high CPU usage was due to returning the buffer to user space too quickly.  If you are interested in the final code, I can post it.

Comment: Also, I apologize for answering your comment nearly a year later.